# bitwise operators for finding less than in c

Tags: c, bitwise-operators

This is a homework assignment which requires me to come up with a function to determine if `x < y`, if it is I must return `1`, using only bitwise operators `( ! ~ & ^ | + << >> )`. I am only allowed to use constants `0 - 0xFF`, and assume a 32-bit integer.  No loops, casting, etc.

What I  have figured out is that if you were to only examine say 4 bits you can do `x - y` to determine if `x` is less than `y`.  If `x` was `8` and `y` was `9` the result would be `1111` for `-1`.

```
int lessThan(int x, int y){
    int sub = x + (~y+1);
```

What I am confused about is how to go about now comparing that result with `x` to determine that it is indeed less than `y`.

I have been examining this article [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10096599/3160529).

But I am a bit confused by that approach to the problem. I have worked out the shifting to attain the **bit smearing** but am confused about how you go about using that result to compare the values as less than or greater than.  I am just looking for a little guidance and clarity, not a solution, that is not my intent.

Comment: When did `!` and `+` become bitwise operators? Are you sure they're legal?

Comment: yes I am sure they are legal, I suppose I should have said I am only allowed to use these arithmetic and logical operators.  Sorry.

Comment: allowed both ints and unsigned.

Comment: I'm familiar with both this homework assignment and this class.  Rather than giving you an answer, here's an approach to try:  Consider the signs of both x and y, then break the comparison into four cases.  You can simplify the solution from there.

Comment: thank you, I think that is what I was struggling with.

Answer (score 3):

I think it can be achived doing following:

1. Xor both numbers, that will give you bits that differs
2. Get the most significant bit that differs, as this one will make a difference
3. Check if that most significant bit belongs to bigger value

Code:

```
int less(int x, int y) {
    //Get only diffed bits
    int msb = x ^ y;
    //Get first msb bit
    msb |= (msb >>  1);
    msb |= (msb >>  2);
    msb |= (msb >>  4);
    msb |= (msb >>  8);
    msb |= (msb >> 16);
    msb = msb - (msb >> 1);
    //check if msb belongs to y;
    return !((y & msb) ^ msb);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The idea of implementing subtraction is good.

```
int sub = x + (~y+1);
```

From here, you just need to check whether `sub` is negative, i.e. extract its sign bit. This is where the technical difficulty appears.

Let's assume `x` and `y` are unsigned 32-bit integers. Then the result of subtraction can be represented by a signed 33-bit integer (check its minimum and maximum values to see that). That is, using the expression `x + (~y+1)` directly doesn't help, because it will overflow.

What if `x` and `y` were 31-bit unsigned numbers? Then, `x + (~y+1)` can be represented by a 32-bit signed number, and its sign bit tells us whether `x` is smaller than `y`:

```
answer(x, y) := ((x + (~y+1)) >> 31) & 1
```

To convert `x` and `y` from 32 bits to 31 bits, separate their MSB (most significant bit) and all the other 31 bits into different variables:

```
msb_x = (x >> 31) & 1;
msb_y = (y >> 31) & 1;
x_without_msb = x << 1 >> 1;
y_without_msb = y << 1 >> 1;
```

Then consider the 4 possible combinations of their MSB:

```
if (msb_x == 0 && msb_y == 0)
    return answer(x_without_msb, y_without_msb);
else if (msb_x == 1 && msb_y == 0)
    return 0; // x is greater than y
else if (msb_x == 0 && msb_y == 1)
    return 1; // x is smaller than y
else
    return answer(x_without_msb, y_without_msb);
```

Converting all these if-statements to a single big ugly logical expression is "an exercise for the reader".

Answer (score 0):

Here was my attempt (compiling results, x > y then 0, x < y then 1, x == y then 1):

```
((((x + ~y) >> 31) + 1))^1
```

Comment: I think you need to add 1 first. `-y = ~y+1` in two complement

Comment: This may be good enough for the homework assignment, but it fails when there is overflow.

Comment: Since when was `3 < 3` true?

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to add to this discussion, since I'm not sure if it's been mentioned yet. Some here have brought up that

```
( x + ((~y) + 1)) >> 32) & 0x1
```

will not work for overflow conditions. For two's complement numbers, overflow conditions for adding integers x and y are:

x > 0, y > 0, (x+y) < 0

x < 0, y < 0, (x+y) > 0

In this case, we're adding x and (-y) together, and must also check for overflow conditions before determining whether (x-y)<0

```
long isLess(long x, long y) {
    long xs= (x>>63) & 0x1L; 
    long ys= (y>>63) & 0x1L;
    long s = x + (~y +1L);

    long ss= (s>>63) & 0x1L;

    /*
    //Code without SOP result for clarity
    if(xs & ~ys & ~ss) return 1;
    if(~xs & ys & ss)  return 0;

    return ss;
    */

    return (((xs | ~ys | ~ss) & (~xs | ys | ss)) & ss) |
           (((~xs & ys & ss) | (xs & ~ys & ~ss)) & ~ss);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In order to know if `x < y`, you can simply ask if `x - y < 0`.

In other words, what is the sign of the result of `x - y`.

Since you stated you are to assume 32 bit integers, following will provide the correct result:

```
((x - y) >> 31) & 0x1
```

Comment: Added `& 0x1` in case the sign extended shift takes place

Comment: @ChrisDodd Correct