# How to write a LessThan method without using the operator

Tags: java, math, recursion, integer, integer-arithmetic

How would you recursively write a method that checks if a number is less than the other without using the '<' operator?

1. You can only use the plus, minus, times, and equals operators.
2. It must be recursive
3. `x` and `y` will always be 0 or greater
4. Should return `boolean`
5. If needed, you can make other methods but they must follow rules above.

Cove I've got so far:

```
public static boolean isLessThan(int x, int y) { 
    if(x == y - 1) return true;
    if(x == y + 1) return false; 
    if(x == y) return false; 

    return isLessThan((x), (y-1)) || isLessThan((x-1), y);
}
```

Comment: Is bit-wise operator allowed?

Comment: public static boolean isLessThan(int x, int y) {
  if(x == y - 1) return true;
  if(x == y + 1) return false;
  if(x == y) return false;
  return isLessThan((x), (y-1)) || isLessThan((x-1), y);
 }

Comment: @ErfanAhmedEmon Sorry, Bitwise "And" and "Or" is allowed

Comment: you have used minus operator in your code but you said ''only use the plus, times, and equals operators''. Does that mean minus is also allowed?

Comment: @ErfanAhmedEmon minus is allowed, sorry for the confusion

Comment: You're close. Two questions: 1) What happens to `LessThan(3,1)`? 2) What is motivating you to have two branches of recursion?

Comment: @MFisherKDX 1. We get a stack overflow 2. I'm trying to consider the 2 cases where we could have (1, 3) or (3, 1) and not sure how to distinguish between both in the code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because you have made a good-faith attempt by writing your own code, and because I see this is a kind of puzzle, I'm offering you below code which has only a single recursive call rather than having two recursive calls like in your code.

I think this is as simple as it gets while satisfying the constraints.

What it does: it counts down both numbers to zero, and checks which one reaches zero first. If both reach zero at the same time, the result should be false, but simply checking whether `y` is zero already includes that check.

```
public static boolean isLessThan(int x, int y) {
    if (y == 0) {
        return false;
    }
    if (x == 0) {
        return true;
    }

    return isLessThan(x - 1, y - 1);
}
```

@Andreas' answer is more efficient than the above. My aim initially was for a short, clean answer. 
I've tried to create a shorter bitshift approach.
Although harder to grasp than the counting example, it has a better complexity and it has an equal amount of lines as the above code (I'm not counting that constant as I could include it inside the code at the expense of readability).

Note that this code shifts left rather than right and - it checks the most significant bit first.

```
public static final int HIGH_BIT = 1 << 31;

public static boolean isLessThan(int x, int y) {
    if (x == y) {
        return false;
    }
    if ((x & HIGH_BIT) != (y & HIGH_BIT)) {
        return (y & HIGH_BIT) == HIGH_BIT;
    }
    return isLessThan(x << 1, y << 1);
}
```

Note: if `!=` is disallowed, you can change the second `if` statement to:

```
if (((x ^ y) & HIGH_BIT) == HIGH_BIT)
```

Also note that the complexity is really `O(1)` as, although the algorithm is theoretically `O(log n)`, Java ints are 32 bits so the upper bounds is `O(32)` which is the same as `O(1)`.

Comment: Thank you so much, I think I was overthinking this one.

Comment: What if negative value of `x` or `y` is given?

Comment: @ErfanAhmedEmon See rule 3: *`x` and `y` will always be 0 or greater*

Comment: oh! my bad. Sorry for overlooking that.

Comment: `isLessThan(40000, 40000)` ➜ `StackOverflowError`

Comment: @Andreas Funny, my Turing machine has no problems running the code ;-) I think this problem sort of follows from the requirements but I'd be happy to upvote an answer that handles this (apart from including a check for x == y as that wouldn't help for `(40000, 40001)`). And in any case, I could seriously run it with `(40000, 40000)` by providing `-Xss1G` on the command line.

Comment: `(x & HIGH_BIT) != (y & HIGH_BIT)` can be replaced with `(x  ^ y) & HIGH_BIT`

Answer (score 2):

You could do it like the answer to this question:
[Bitwise operations equivalent of greater than operator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10096599/5221149)

However that doesn't honor rule 2: *It must be recursive.*

According to [comment](http://You%20can%20only%20use%20the%20plus,%20minus,%20times,%20and%20equals%20operators.), rule 1 should be:

1. You can only use *plus*, *minus*, *multiply*, *equals*, and *bitwise* operators.

With the use of the *right-shift* operator, we can get a solution in *O(log n)* time, unlike [answer by Erwin Bolwidt](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46870338/5221149), which is *O(n)* time, and likely to cause `StackOverflowError`.

```
public static boolean isLessThan(int x, int y) {
    return compare(x, y) == -1;
}

private static int compare(int x, int y) {
    if (x == y)
        return 0;  // x == y
    if (x == 0)
        return -1; // x < y
    if (y == 0)
        return 1;  // x > y

    // Compare higher bits. If different, then that is result
    int cmp = compare(x >> 1, y >> 1);
    if (cmp != 0)
        return cmp;

    // Only bit 0 differs, so two choices:
    //   x0 == 1 && y0 == 0 -> return 1
    //   x0 == 0 && y0 == 1 -> return -1
    return (x & 1) - (y & 1);
}
```

If `!=` is not allowed, code can be changed to:

```
// same code up to and including recursive call
if (cmp == 0)
    return (x & 1) - (y & 1);
return cmp;
```

Comment: That is indeed a more efficient recursive implementation, +1.